# vba print in excel

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I want to use an excel macro to print a sheet. I'd like to populate the sheet and print it, then repopulate it with new data and print again for various sheets.
That works but each sheet is a new print job. Is there a way to make them all print as a single print job?
Thank for any help available.

Was hoping to find a way for all sheets to print as a single job. Especially desirable when printing to a file so that I don't have to provide file names for each sheet printed.

Comment: Two options, you need to go through the "fun" task of figuring out how to combine each print job with whatever adobe library you have at your disposal, or you can make them each a different sheet and print entire workbook.